# What is grpc-gateway equivalent in ASP.Net, to send proto messages using REST API on HTTP/1.1?

Tags: grpc, .net-7.0, .net-8.0, grpc-dotnet, grpc-gateway

I have used grpc-gateway in past and was able to get that working to send protobuf on http/1.1.

This time i have .Net grpc service on backend but due to not all clients supporting Http2, i have similar requirement of REST API on HTTP/1.1 request / response  on protobuf for my .Net grpc service.

ASP.NET Grpc Json Transcoding looked promising but seems its only working on JSON and I am not able to make protobuf working. Is that it's limitation or I am missing something?

Are there any other alternatives, is envoy-proxy the only way out for me? To make HTTP/1.1 proto messages to work?

Or grpc-web is better approach?

Any help around this is appreciative.